# How to make this dropdown ease down

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a dropdown menu and want to make it an ease down transition. Can somebody help?

The dropdown property marks the total dropdown div.
The dropdown-content property marks the hidden content

Here's my css properties:

```
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    transition: height .4s ease;
  }

  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block; transition-property: dropdown-content; transition-duration:0.4s;}
```

Here's my associated javascript code:

```
        <div className="flex-1 w-full xs:max-w-none sm:w-full sm:min-w-155 dark:bg-nft-black-3 bg-white rounded-2xl p-4 m-4 sm:my-2 sm:mx-2 cursor-pointer shadow-md dropdown dropbtn">
          ...

          </div>
            <div className='flex flex-row w-full justify-center items-center dropdown-content'>
                <div className='flex w-2/3 pt-2 pb-4 pr-2 text-sm'>
                    {proposal.description}
                </div>
                {proposal.deadline.getTime() > Date.now() && !proposal.executed ? (
                    <div className='flex w-full'>
                    <div className='flex flex-row'>
                        <PostCardButton 
                        btnName={`Vote Yes`}
                        classStyles={"rounded-xl sm-text-sm"}
                        handleClick={() => voteOnProposal(proposalId, "YAY")}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='px-5'>
                        <PostCardButton 
                            btnName={"Vote No"}
                            classStyles={"rounded-xl px-7 sm:text-sm"}
                            handleClick={() => voteOnProposal(proposalId, "NAY")}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                ) : proposal.deadline.getTime() < Date.now() && !proposal.executed ? (
                    <div className='flex flex-row w-full'>
                        <PostCardButton 
                            btnName={`Execute Proposal`}
                            classStyles={"rounded-xl"}
                            handleClick={() => executeProposal(proposalId)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className='flex w-full font-semibold text-lg'>
                        Executed
                        </div>
                    )}
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add the related html code so that others can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're achieving the animation by transitioning `height` property, then the problem is: **you are not changing it in the css classes**.

```
.dropdown-content {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.4s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  height: 360px;
}
```

Also, `dropdown-content` is not an [animatable CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). So, `transition-property: dropdown-content;` cannot be used here.

---

If the height of your content is not constant, then you should use javascript to find it and then change it.

> Using `height: max-content;` will not work.

The easiest way to do this would be to calculate the complete height of dropdown content in both cases [`proposal.deadline.getTime() > Date.now()` and vice versa] and add them in the css.